# Nginx location block that matches a group of urls

Tags: nginx

I have an IdentityAccess controller in my application, that contains four action methods:

1. login
2. check
3. refresh
4. revoke

So, I can access these action methods by localhost/IdentityAccess/login and etc. Besides, I implemented Lua validation, that should secure some of the routes. For example, this is how I secure all requests coming to `store` controller:

```
location /store/ {
    rewrite_by_lua_file 'jwt-validation.lua';
    proxy_pass http://store_server/
    ...
}
```

But the whole problem is with IdentityAccess controller. In this controller I want to secure all action methods except `login`. Besides, I do not want to create a whole bunch of exact locations like `location /IdentityAccess/check { ...`, `location /IdentityAccess/refresh { ...` and etc. and apply to each location Lua script. What I want is some kind of regex that would match a list of action methods - check, refresh and revoke - and would ignore login action method. But I do not know what is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix location with the longest matching prefix is selected. So all you need is define `/IdentityAction/login/` location without jwt validation.

```
location /IdentityAction/ {
    rewrite_by_lua_file 'jwt-validation.lua';
    proxy_pass http://store_server;
    ...
}

location /IdentityAction/login/ {
    proxy_pass http://store_server;
    ...
}
```

Sure, this can be done with regexp location too, but in this case position of location in file is important, because first match selected (but for prefix locations position is not important because best match of location selected). With regexp it can look like

```
location ~ ^/IdentityAction/login/$ {
    # first location in file
    proxy_pass http://store_server;
}

location ~ ^/IdentityAction/$ {
    # second location in file
    rewrite_by_lua_file 'jwt-validation.lua';
    proxy_pass http://store_server;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it tomorrow!

Comment: The only question I have is whether in case of /IdentityAccess/check request, it will be correctly proxied to http://store_server/check and handled by checkAction method ? Should not we fix somehow proxy_pass command in your first location definition?

Comment: Oh, missed it. Need to remove last slash in proxy_pass.

Comment: So, without this slash `/IdentityAccess/check` request will be proxied to `http://store_server/check` route?

Comment: Ah, got you question. No, it will be proxied to `http://store_server/IdentityAccess/check`. If you need `http://store_server/check` -  slash required for `/IdentityAction/` location. And for login location `proxy_pass http://store_server/login/;` But only for prefix locations, for regexp location can differ.

Comment: So, inside `/IdentityAccess/` I will have `proxy_pass http://store_server/;` with a trailing slash? So, that some arbitrary request like `/IdentityAccess/check` will be proxied to `http://store_server/check`. And inside `/IdentityAction/login/` location I would have `proxy_pass http://store_server/login/`?

Comment: Yes. Simple rule - path part in `proxy_pass` replacing path part of `location`.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it today one more time!

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass about this logic can read here